# Swap array elements in c

Tags: c

I hope you can help. I am trying to write a program that 'given a list(array) of 10 integers, find the one with the smallest absolute value and swap its position with the last one and output the new list.

Here's what I have coded but its not swaping..

```
#include stdio.h
#include math.h

int main() {

    int array[10];
    int arraynew[10];
    int absmallest = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
    absmallest = array[0];

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (abs(array[i]) < absmallest)
            absmallest = array[i];
        index = i;
    }

    int temp;
    temp = array[9];
    array[9] = array[index];
    array[index] = temp;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d", array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is index == 9? Try tracing index with a printf statement or debugging.

Comment: You need to put index = i inside the if. For this kind of problems, you should use a debugger to step through your code, and you should be able to notice your code wasn't executing in the way you want.

Comment: @user1582136 Don't forget to select the best answer! Selecting a best answer gives you 2 points, the answerer 15, and, moreover, will encourage people to answer your questions in the future. When you ask a question, a % accepted appears. The lower the percentage, the lower the chance of a good answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your `index` inside the `if`-statement.

```
if (abs(array[i]) < absmallest)
    absmallest = array[i];
index = i;
```

should be

```
if (abs(array[i]) < absmallest)
{
    absmallest = array[i];
    index = i;
}
```

Otherwise, you update your `index` on each loop.

---

**EDIT:** As @amit noted, you also need to store the absolute value, not the real one. In other words

```
absmallest = array[i];
```

should be

```
absmallest = abs( array[i] );
```

And the same for the initialization of `absmallest`

```
absmallest = abs( array[0] );
```

Comment: Though correct, unfortunately, it is not enough. What will the program do on input: `{-99, 0 , 1, 2, ... } `

Comment: @amit - thanks, you're right. I'll upvote your competitive answer :)

Answer (score 3):

two issues:

**(1)**

```
    if (abs(array[i]) < absmallest)
        absmallest = array[i];
    index = i;
```

The `index = i` is out of the scope of the if statement - so it happens every iteration, and does not depends on the result of your condition.

**(2)** 

`absmallest = array[0];` should be with `abs()` as well (what happens if `array[0] = -5`)?
Same goes for the assignment of `abssmallest` in the for loop (`absmallest = array[i];` should be `absmallest = abs(array[i]);`)

Comment: Only answer so far to catch the issue with not storing the abs value

Answer (score 0):

In this loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (abs(array[i]) < absmallest)
        absmallest = array[i];
    index = i;
}
```

You set the variable `index` *every* time. Which means that when the loop if over `index` will be the index to the last element.

Also, you should probably initialize `absmallest` to `abs(array[0])` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (abs(array[i]) < absmallest)
    absmallest = array[i];
index = i;
```

should become

```
if (abs(array[i]) < absmallest) {
    absmallest = array[i];
    index = i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     if (abs(array[i]) < absmallest)
         absmallest = array[index = i];
}
```